# Installing Unreal Engine on OSX Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

So I'm trying to clone the Unreal Engine from GitHub and setup on OSX Mojave and when running the GenerateProjectFiles.command file as part of the setup, I get the following error:

> ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception: Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs

I do have a folder called MacOSX.sdk in a different directory, but when I try to create a symlink to it in the directory that Unreal is searching for, I get this following error instead:

> ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception: Unable to find installed MacOS SDK on remote agent.

It seems like I'm missing the correct version of the MacOSX.sdk that Unreal needs but I'm not sure what that is. I know you get it when you install XCode, but I have both XCode 10.1 and XCode 9.4 with command line tools installed and still no luck.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and find a measure for my case.

> sudo xcode-select --reset

from [here](https://www.devoops.kr/16)

Answer (score 0):

you need the correct version of xcode with the specific version of unreal.
for unreal engine 4.24 or earlier, you need to install xcode 11 from here:[Download xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).for 4.25 or later, use xcode 12 or later if you haven't installed.
if not use `sudo xcode-select --reset`